# Error while trying to install geos 3.4.2 on os x

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, geos

I get the following error messages:

```
make[4]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I am running os x 10.6.8 with Xcode 4.2. Following [these suggestions](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/7049), I tried to install it with --use-gcc but that didn't make any difference. Any ideas what might cause the errors?

Comment: It looks like this error is due to the 3.4 release of geos being packaged with files containing carriage-return line endings. (It was packaged on a windows machine rather than UNIX.)  Here is the relevant [ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/ticket/645).

Comment: The actual error is not shown. Were there more error messages above?